# UIActivityIndicator not showing up

Tags: iphone

I have a login for in which i need an activityindicator to be shown just after i press login button. In the button action i am calling my method to login a user (i have called [sratAnimating] in the top of the method).

But issue is that, when i press login, after excecuting the logic only its showing activity indicator. Why is this ? any way to show this first and then the logic execution ? plz help

Answer (score 4):

Try to start indicator in other thread

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *aInd;
...
[aInd performSelectorInBackground: @selector(startAnimating) withObject: nil];
```